# CI build working but deployment to Azure is not triggered

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I created an MVC project using VS 2013 and added it to Visual Studio Team Services. I've also created an Azure website and linked it to the project. I created a CI build profile and the build triggers correctly on check-in. No problems, no errors.

However, the project is not being deployed. There are no errors in the build, and I don't see any way to manually trigger the deployment once the build appears in Visual Studio Online. It seems that everything between Visual Studio and visualstudio.com is working, but the link between the Azure website and VS Team Services is not working. Azure shows no deployments.

Any thoughts on what might be the issue or how I can diagnose the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I was using the wrong deployment template in the build profile. I should have been using the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml template